# How to remove an island from a UV map?

Tags: uv

I unwrapped my head in one UV map and the unwrapped head still appears in the map when I create a new UV map. How do I remove the head island from my new map? Is sliding it out of the image the only solution?

Here is an illustration of what I am requesting if it makes any sense.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sliding it out would not fix the problem. The image repeats. If you want to "remove" it, you could scale it down to 0 and put it in the corner or wherever you want. alternatively, you could assign it to a different material slot and not worry about the uv map, or separate it into a different object and have it as a different uv map entirely. Those are the only ways I see of fixing this.

Comment: hi and thnks for the response I actually updated the post to make it more clear what im asking for.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

To add a new UV map just clique the plus under Object Data Properties/UV Map.
To remove completely (deleting) a UV map just go to the minus icon. If you would like to switch between them just unchek the one ot the other.

Comment: hi and thnks for the response I actually updated the post to make it more clear what im asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Select the UV map that you want to use from the list of UV's
[image]

Comment: hi and thnks for the response I actually updated the post to make it more clear what im asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Deselect the head in the viewport and it should disappear from the UV map.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, I believe I've had this problem in the past. What fixed it for me was what someone else already suggested. Go to the object data properties on the right side and delete the UV Map that was added by default when you did the Unwrap command. Now do another unwrap and it will not lay over the top of your old unwrap. Hope that helps.